# 있다던데 vs 있다기에: why is 있다던데 wrong in this case?

Tags: grammar, meaning

The answer is 4 (있다기에) but why is 3 (있다던데) wrong here?
[image]

**EDIT**:  why can't -다던데 be used like this?
[image]

Comment: What is the question? I mean, what were you asked to do?

Comment: For 해서 (= 하여서), you need to read the second definition of [-여서](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?nation=eng&ParaWordNo=80210). You will find that [-기에](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?wordMatchFlag=N&mainSearchWord=-%EA%B8%B0%EC%97%90&currentPage=1&sort=W&searchType=W&proverbType=&exaType=&ParaWordNo=84811&nation=eng&nationCode=6&viewType=A&blockCount=10&viewTypes=on&myViewWord=80210) is a synonym of -여서. [-다기에](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?&ParaWordNo=82207&nation=eng&nationCode=6) equals -다고 하기에.

Comment: @Klmo the question asked for the one that can exchange with the underlined part. I know 다기에 but I'm wondering why 다던데 can't be used in this case.

Comment: It is just because -다던데 (= -다고 하던데) is not interchangeable with -다고 해서. The dictionary definition of -다던데 is unclear, but, for that specific meaning, people never use -다던데 in place of -다고 해서. No one will fully understand what you are saying if you use -다고 해서 instead of -다던데 in those example sentences.

Comment: @Klmo -다던데 isn't exchangeable with -다고 해서 but does it still make sense in that case? From what you said, it seems like it's weird to use -다던데 there. You said that the dictionary is not clear. So what's the good definition of it?

Comment: "... 효과가 있다던데 해 보는 거예요" does not make sense at all. Well, I have not seen a clear definition of -다던데. To me, it is somewhat inexplainable.

Comment: @Klmo why can't you use it like 효과가 있다던데 해 보는 거예요 = I heard that it's effective so I try it?

Comment: That is not where -다던데 is used. You should not try to understand a sentence in English. Korean is Korean. There are things that you will never understand if you stick to translations.

Answer (score 2):

- 있다기에 = 있다 + 기에
  기에 is a conjunctive ending to indicate a **cause, factor and reason**.

ex) 
효과가 있다기에 -> 해 보는 거예요.
Because I heard it is good for relaxing my eyes -> so I'm trying this.

친구가 왔다기에 -> 인사하러 달려 갔어요. 
Because my friend arrived -> so I ran to say hello to her.

- 있다던데 = 있다 + 던데

1) 던데 is a conjunctive ending that recall some fact of the past and mention it in order to **explain, ask, order and suggest** something.

ex)
너 고향에 자주 가던데 집에 무슨 일 있니? 
I noticed that you've visited your hometown very often recently. Is there any problem?

너 그림을 잘 그렸던데 그거 여기에 걸자.
I remember that your painting was awesome. How about hanging it here?

2) The second meaning of 던데 is a final ending to convey the exclamation about something that happened in the past and also it shows that the speaker is waiting for the response of the listener. (it is the literal meaning in the dictionary)

ex)
이거 맛있던데. I remember that it was delicious. (and the speaker is expecting the listener to respond to his saying.)

So, if you say 효과가 있던데, you need to say something to explain, ask order and suggest after that. But 해 보는 거예요 is not the case so it is not correct.

효과가 있다던데 해 보는 거예요 (x)

효과가 있다던데 너도 해볼래? (o)

효과가 있다던데 우리 해보자. (o)

Comment: How about this 다던데? 
https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?wordMatchFlag=N&mainSearchWord=%EB%8B%A4%EB%8D%98%EB%8D%B0&currentPage=1&sort=W&searchType=W&proverbType=&exaType=&ParaWordNo=82094&nation=eng&nationCode=6&viewType=A&blockCount=10&viewTypes=on

Comment: 다던데 is shorten from -다고 하던데. So 다던데 has same meaning and function with 던데.

Comment: could you give an example of -다던데 to explain something?
The two examples you gave are for asking and suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

As I said, the definition(s) of -다던데 is unclear in existing Korean dictionaries; in this case, it is better to know where -던데 is used as 연결 어미 (a connective ending). For -던데, I would suggest using not only [the standard dictionary](https://stdict.korean.go.kr/search/searchView.do?word_no=415348&searchKeywordTo=3) but also [고려대 한국어대사전 (Korea University Korean Dictionary)](https://dic.daum.net/word/view.do?wordid=kkw000064275&q=%EB%8D%98%EB%8D%B0&suptype=KOREA_KK).

The standard dictionary says:

> 1. ((‘이다’의 어간, 용언의 어간 또는 어미 ‘-으시-’, ‘-었-’, ‘-겠-’ 뒤에 붙어)) 뒤 절에서 어떤 일을 **설명하거나 묻거나 시키거나 제안하기 위하여**, 그와 상관있는 과거 사실을 회상하여 미리 말할 때에 쓰는 **연결 어미**.

According to this definition, the purpose of using -던데 is to (1) explain something, (2) ask someone a question, (3) order someone to do something, and (4) suggest doing something, as lingodeerapp mentioned. The examples, however, *do not include* the cases for explanations and orders.

> - 너 고향에 자주 가던데 집에 무슨 일 있니? (Question)
> - 너 그림을 잘 그렸던데 그거 여기에 걸자. (Suggestion)

This is a bit misleading because, when you explain something, *you need to consider one more thing* not mentioned in the standard dictionary.

From Korea University Korean Dictionary, I have found the following definitions and examples for the connective ending -던데:

> **연결 어미**
>
> (1) 용언이나 ‘이다’의 어간 또는 선어말 어미 ‘-으시-’, ‘-었-’, ‘-겠-’의 뒤에 붙어, 다음 말을 이끌어 내기 위하여 그와 관련되는 과거의 사실을 회상하는 뜻을 나타내는 말.
>
> - 오후 두 시 차가 있던데 그걸 타고 갑시다. (Suggestion)
> - 목소리가 아주 감미롭던데 성우 하실 생각은 없나요? (Question)
>
> (2) 용언이나 ‘이다’의 어간 또는 선어말 어미 ‘-으시-’, ‘-었-’, ‘-겠-’의 뒤에 붙어, **과거에 경험한 사실이 뒤에 오는 사실과 대립됨을 나타내는** 말.
>
> - 그녀는 겉보기엔 둔한 것 같던데 이야기를 나누어 보니 명석하더라. (**Explanation**)

The *second* definition suggests that the clause following -던데 should **contradict** the preceding words when you **explain** something. I would say that this is the exact reason that you cannot say "...효과가 있다던데 해 보는 거예요" instead of "...효과가 있다기에 해 보는 거예요."

---

I left [a question regarding -다던데 and -라던데](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/onlineQna/onlineQnaView.do?mn_id=216&qna_seq=185904&pageIndex=1) on the website of National Institute of Korean Language. In spite of their vague explanation, they agreed that these sentences (can) sound awkward:

> - 그 꽃이 그렇게 예쁘다던데 내가 보기에 그 꽃은 예뻐. (✘)
> - 이 운동이 몸에 좋다던데 (내가/나는) 이 운동을 하는 중이야. (✘)
> - 친구가 이리로 가라던데 나는 이리로 가려고 해. (✘)

As you can see, each clause following -던데, which is an *explanation*, does *not* contradict the preceding words. You should *not* use -던데 here.

Plus, you should note that you can ask a question without using a question mark. I mean that you should focus on the meaning of the clause not on its type.

> - 이 운동이 몸에 좋다던데 (그게) 정말인지 (나는) 궁금해. (Question)
> - 이 운동이 몸에 좋다던데 너도 이 운동을 하는지 (나는) 궁금해. (Question)

A question can also be a suggestion as shown in the following:

> 이 운동이 몸에 좋다던데 너도 (이 운동) (나랑) 같이 하지 그러니? (Question + suggestion)

For orders, there are *no reasons* to contradict facts or ideas, so they relate to the *first* definition given in Korea University Korean Dictionary. Please refer to the following examples:

> 이 운동이 몸에 좋다던데 너도 (이 운동) 좀 해. (Order)
>
> 이 운동이 몸에 좋다던데 너도 (이 운동) 해 봐라. (Order, a bit close to suggestion)